# Netbeans 18 Context menu button 'Run file' is grayed out

Tags: java, netbeans

In Netbeans 18 the context menu 'Run file' is grayed-out on a new JFrame, when i open the context menu from somewhere in the code. (Same with the debug file.)

The funny thing is that the context menu opened from the class in the Projects tree is working, as is the Run file from the Run menu.

The class *is* runnable, it has the generated main:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject2;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

What am I missing here?

I would expect to not have the context menu Run file grayed-out if it is not grayed-out in the Run menu.

nb:

- I *can* run the file from the Run menu, and from the Context menu from the Class in the Projects tree.
- I *can* run the project. (Which points to this same JFrame in the properties.)
- I did already save the file (in an older version of Netbeans it only recognized the main after save).
- Even after closing and reopening Netbeans the context menu is still grayed-out.
- I use OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-2724)
- The menu is not grayed-out on a manually created (runnable) class, after save. (Also extending JFrame and with the exact same main.) (Even before i save this file. !?)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I can select and use the **Run File** entry in the context menu shown from the source of the class with the generated **main()** method. I can't see that you have done anything wrong, especially since you can run the project from the **Run** menu. Can you update your question to include the complete source of the class with `main()`? And if that is not feasible, create simpler version of your class that reproduces the problem, and update your question with that. Unless others can reproduce your unusual problem by copying your code this will be tough to diagnose.

Comment: Also update your question with your versions of NetBeans and Java to allow others to properly attempt to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I updated the question to have the full generated class (i did delete some comments).
Also added the version of NetBeans and Java.

If I manually create a class with exactly the same content, the problem does not occur.
(The only difference i see with that is that the manually created class does not have a .form file and does not show a design tab.)

Comment: My assumption for now (after playing with the files and manually creating the same) is that it is some NetBeans bug.

Comment: It may be a NetBeans bug, but I can't reproduce your problem. I started NB 18 with OpenJDK 17.0.2+8-86, created a Maven project, copied your `NewJFrame` class, and could successfully **Run File** from the context menu for the source code. There is a very old unresolved NetBeans bug for a similar issue, [Bug 242261 - Run File menu is disabled eventhough main() method is available in a class](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=242261). It doesn't seem to be relevant for your issue, but you might try the workaround mentioned in comment 26.

Comment: Also, the keyboard equivalent for the grayed context menu entry for **Run File** is _Shift + F6_. That also works for me, and runs the file. Does it work for you?

Comment: I reïnstalled Netbeans and, for the original class where i had the issue, things are now working as normal. (So i do not know if just using the keyboard shortcut would have worked.)
@skomisa: Thanks a lot for your input. At least i'm more confident that it is not some weird setting that i accidentally threw off. Thanks!